# Click on a sub-element using Selenium and Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Please consider the following code example:

```
latest_card = driver.find_elements( By.CSS_SELECTOR , "div[class^='foo-card']" )[-1]
lnk = latest_card.find_element( By.LINK_TEXT , "Request" )

print (">", lnk.text, "->", lnk )
print (">", lnk.get_attribute('href'))

lnk.click() #ERROR
```

`latest_card` is the last element of a list of `divs` that contain various information, including a button (`<a href="..." class="..."> Request </a>`). Additionally, `lnk` is a sub-element of `latest_card`, which is the button.

The code fails at the point where `lnk.click()` is called, with the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
```

Nevertheless, I am able to access the sub-element as shown by the output below:

```
> Request -> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6ac7f41b734ad50fa4a6a90a18845038", element="cb97e8bd-a44a-4f3d-bfcd-4445bd864371")
> https://foobar.com
```

Any ideas why the sub-element is not clickable?

An example of the HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="foo-card">
    <div class="foo-card-wrapper">
        <div class="img-overlay"></div>
        <div class="card-labels-right"></div>
        <div class="card-status-bar"></div>
        <div class="card-body pt-0"></div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="card-actions">
                <a href="foobar.com" class="btn">Request</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the direct `HTML` source for the `lnk` and `latest_card` element ?

Comment: @Akzy: Sorry, I cannot distribute the original code (company rights), but I can try to provide a more detailed example.

Comment: `element click intercepted` implies something is on top of your element or  it's not visible on the screen.  Try scolling the element into view with js or validate in devtools there are no elements overlaying the screen (such as chat support windows or cookie popups)

Comment: @RichEdwards: I will try the scrolling bit, because I was not aware of this limitation, but I can guarantee that there are no overlays.

Comment: @RichEdwards: Sorry, that did not work.

Comment: Btw, `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",lnk)` works. Also, it is possible to get the link by using `driver.get_attribute('href')` and then use `driver.get(...)` to open the page. But I am more interested to find why the sub-element is not clickable.

Comment: If the element is defenitley on screen, if it's maximised and if you're debugging to ensure there's no sync issues - Then is most likely overlaying objects. Kick open devtools, and go up through the object heirarchy to see if something is being drawn by the CSS which persisits over your element.  Drill down into the exception and it tells you why: `class ElementClickInterceptedException(WebDriverException):
    """
    The Element Click command could not be completed because the element receiving the events is obscuring the element that was requested to be clicked.
   """`